# Does Spring follow any naming convention for application configuration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**Issue :
**Configuration defined in application.properties is not overridden by environment variable**.**

I'm facing strange issue with spring configuration as configuration defined in `application.properties` is not overridden by environment variable when configuration is named in specific way. As mentioned in [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) OS environment variables takes precedence over `application.properties` but this doesn't happen when configuration is defined as `myExternal_url` but it works when configuration is defined as `my_external_url` (in sample code below, we need to change configuration to `my_external_url` in `ApplicationProperties.java` and `application.properties`)

Sample Code -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ConfigApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

  @Autowired private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfigApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(ApplicationArguments arg0) {
    System.out.println("External URL = " + applicationProperties.getMyExternalUrl());
  }
}
```

Application Bean configuration -

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")
  public ApplicationProperties applicationProperties() {
    return new ApplicationProperties();
  }
}
```

`ApplicationProperties` class -

```
public class ApplicationProperties {

  @Value("${myExternal_url}")
  private String myExternalUrl;

  public String getMyExternalUrl() {
    return this.myExternalUrl;
  }

  public void setMyExternalUrl(String myExternalUrl) {
    this.myExternalUrl = myExternalUrl;
  }
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
myExternal_url=external_url_env_application_properties
```

What could be reason for this ?

EDIT - adding gradle
Gradle configuration

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0-M1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

EDIT 2

Trace log shows that myExternal_url is resolved correctly from Environment variable. Then Spring tries to resolve autowired dependencies '`applicationProperties`' by calling `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and then value is overridden by application.properties value (screen shot).

```
o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'myExternal_url' in PropertySource 'systemEnvironment' with value of type String
o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'myExternal_url' in PropertySource 'environmentProperties' with value of type String
```

[image: Debug ApplicationProperties]

Comment: Can't reproduce. It uses the environment variable for me.

Comment: I have added build.gradle

Comment: How is the OS environment variable defined? Is it really defined as `myExternal_url` or is it perhaps `my_external_url`? The latter would make sense seeing as only then you are actually referring to the OS env variable instead of the one defined in your application.properties file.

Comment: myExternal_url (in this case it's overridden by OS environment variable).

Comment: Did you try after removing the `@Value` annotation?

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with `@Value` annotation. But I'm wondering why it works for `my_external_url` and doesn't work with `myExternal_url`

Comment: When you use `my_external_url`, there is no relaxed binding. It is two properties with exact name so it chooses the correct one. As I put it in my answer below, it is to do with your `@Value` annotation and that is not needed

Comment: What do you mean by `my_external_url`, there is no relaxed binding ? If there is relaxed binding then it should apply to both application.properties and environment variable, shouldn't it ?

Comment: But spring didn't say that it will do so. The document only says it will apply to `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: @KavithakaranKanapathippillai - just to confirm what environment variable you are specifying when it's not reproducible for you MY_EXTERNAL_URL or myExternal_url ?

Comment: I first tried to reproduce it with `env` name of `MY_EXTERNAL_URL` and then tried to reproduce it with `env` name of `my_external_url`. Then I removed the `@Value` annotation as it is not part of the contract

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR `@Value` has correct `myExternal_Url` from system variables injected, but its value is later set by `@ConfigurationProperties`.

The trace log is correct in that the ordering from Spring will place `systemEnvironment` before `classpath:/application.properties` in the propertySource list.

The issue you are having is because of a combination of using both `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties` to inject/bind your properties.
Say these are the values you provide:

```
system:
  myExternal_Url: foo
  my_external_url: bar
applications.properties:
  myExternal_url: aaa
```

In your ApplicationProperties:

```
  @Value("${myExternal_url}")
  private String myExternalUrl; // injected with foo
```

`myExternalUrl` is injected correctly with value (`foo`) you defined in your Environment Variables. However, `@ConfigurationProperties` binds the values **after** by using the setter methods. Since it uses relaxed bindings, it checks for different variations of `myExternalUrl`, it first looks for what's in your system variables and finds that `myExternal_url`(both camel and Underscore) isn't in one of relaxed binding forms , but then `my_external_url` (underscore only) is. So `my_external_url`'s value is provided to setter:

```
public void setMyExternalUrl(String myExternalUrl) { // bar
  this.myExternalUrl = myExternalUrl; // myExternalUrl is reassigned from foo to bar
}
```

So it should be clear that your `@Value` would always be overridden since `@ConfigurationProperties` binds values after. Simply have:

```
public class ApplicationProperties {
    private String myExternalUrl;
    ...
```

then have one of binding forms - `MY_EXTERNAL_URL`, `my-external-url`, or `my_external_url`(Maybe there is more) - defined in your system. Then have consistent case in your application.yml in case you don't want your system variables.

```
my-external-url=aaa
```

Side Note. It is recommended that you use the form `MY_EXTERNAL_URL` as system environment variables.

Answer (score 6):

Spring indeed supports some sort of naming convention in the form of relaxed binding (as pointed by @Kavithakaran Kanapathippillai). In case of [@ConfigurationProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-typesafe-configuration-properties) and @Value annotation,  Spring tries to resolve variable from Configuration Source in the order as defined in [Externalized Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.2.2.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) using [relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding).

As answered @夢のの夢 - spring correctly match property using `@Value("${myExternal_url}")` with environment variable but later overridden by `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")`.

As bean `ApplicationProperties` is defined as `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")`, Spring tries to match variable with configuration source (using relaxed binding) and finds match in application.propertied variable `myExternalUrl` and overrides property resolved using `@Value("${myExternal_url}")`. Problem lies in using both `@Value` and `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")`.

Side note - `@Value` supports [limited relaxed binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-vs-value) and **Spring recommends @Value property names to be defined using kebab-case**.

From documentation -

> If you do want to use @Value, we recommend that you refer to property
> names using their canonical form (kebab-case using only lowercase
> letters). This will allow Spring Boot to use the same logic as it does
> when relaxed binding @ConfigurationProperties. For example,
> @Value("{demo.item-price}") will pick up demo.item-price and
> demo.itemPrice forms from the application.properties file, as well as
> DEMO_ITEMPRICE from the system environment. If you used
> @Value("{demo.itemPrice}") instead, demo.item-price and DEMO_ITEMPRICE
> would not be considered.

Comment: `@Value("${myExternal_url}")` is injected correctly if you turn on debugging. So It is actually looking for `myExternal_url` correctly and not `my-external-url`.`@ConfigurationProperties` simply takes place after `@Value` and hence overrides the value of `myExternalUrl` with setter.  The problem here is that `@ConfigurationProperties` doesn't match for `myExternal_url` since it uses relaxed binding and only pick up `myExternalUrl`, `my-external-url` and `my_external_url` etc

Comment: Yes you are right. If I remove `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "")` then it works fine. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I see. There is some limited relaxed binding support for `@Value` as well

Answer (score 2):

- I cannot reproduce your issue in `2.3.1.RELEASE` and is working as expected and is overridden by my environment variable.
- However I don't see the spring document where it says, `@Value("${myExternal_url}")` use relaxed binding as well. All I see is `@ConfigurationProperties` will use relaxed binding.

  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding
- So I would update your class as follows (even through it works with and without in `2.3.1.RELEASE`) **`@Value` annotation removed**

```
    public class ApplicationProperties {

      private String myExternalUrl;

      public String getMyExternalUrl() {
        return this.myExternalUrl;
      }

      public void setMyExternalUrl(String myExternalUrl) {
        this.myExternalUrl = myExternalUrl;
      }
    }
```

- Please note, both properties will be still present in the `Environment` but when it is binding, it seems to decide if one overrides the other. You can see this by printing. Here I am getting the `environment` from `applicationContext` but you can `autowire` `Environment` and test this

```
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment()
                             .getProperty("myExternal_url"));
        System.out.println(context.getEnvironment()
                             .getProperty("my_external_url"));
```

- To confirm the above point that only `@ConfigurationProperties` support relaxed binding but not `@Value`. I created the following class

```
   @Component
   public class ValueInjection {
    // This prints application properties.
    @Value("${myExternal_url}")
    private String myExternal_url;

    // This prints the environment variable
    @Value("${my_external_url}")
    private String my_external_url;

// If you uncomment this the application will not start saying 
// there is no such property.
// 
//    @Value("${myExternalUrl}")
//    private String myExternalUrl;

 //   ... getters and setters
    }
```